# EXCEL formula - CountIf - how to exclude cells that meet a certain criteria

Tags: excel, countif

[image: Screenshot]

Hi,

I need help with my excel formula on counting data.

Given my attached screenshot, I need to count all oranges that are "normal" or "not derp".

I tried countif-ing my oranges minus all entries of "derp" but this also affected my formula count for apples.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You can use `CountIf()` for adding one criterium, and you can use `CountIfs()` for multiple ones.

Answer (score 0):

So, assuming your range is is cells A2 to B8, then:

```
=countifs(A2:A8,"Oranges",B2:B8,"normal")+countifs(A2:A8,"Oranges",B2:B8,"derp")
```

You should be able to sort any variation from there.

[image]